# How to make several objects move in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I call a function to make 3 fish move? This is what I have:

```
var fillPosition = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    horizontal[i] = fillPosition;
    fillPosition += 10;
}
function fish1Swim() {
    document.getElementById("fish1").style.left = horizontal[fish1Position] + "px";
    ++fish1Position;
    if (fish1Position == 49)
            fish1Position = 0;
}
 function startSwimming() {
    setInterval(fish1Swim, 100);
}
```

I am thinking I should var each fish  but I really don't understand.

Comment: The easy way out : Using a js animation library

Comment: I done read somethings and still dont understand

Comment: Try out the tutorials on the frameworks that Teoman Soygul posted. They are very basic

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel, use one of the JavaScript animation libraries here: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/

and read the js animation tutorial here: http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/

Comment: The link above doesn't seem to mention jQuery's animation...and it should!